# Flutter does not redirect Azure API request after login

Tags: flutter, azure, dart, oauth, dio

I'm trying to call Azure APIs in a Flutter application. I use [aad_oauth](https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth) package.
I successfully login and I can get the Microsoft access token, but when I call a GET API passing the bearer token as Authorization header, I cannot get the expected JSON response.

This is the aad_oauth Configuration:

```
static final Config config = Config(
tenant: '***',
clientId: '***',
scope: 'openid profile offline_access',
navigatorKey: Get.key,
redirectUri: '***',
loader: SizedBox());

static final AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(config);
```

**LoginViewModel.dart**

```
final result = await oAuth.login();
String accessToken = await oAuth.getAccessToken();
```

The access token is retrieved and stored correctly.

This is the API call, using Dart [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio):

```
  @override
  Future<ShipGroupModel?> getShips() async {
    try {
      final Response<dynamic> response = await _dio.get(
        "/api/ship",
      );
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      // exception handling
    }
}
```

But this is the response body:

```
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
      <head>
          <title>Sign in to your account</title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
          <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
          <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://aadcdn.msauth.net" crossorigin>
      <meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msauth.net">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msftauth.net">
      
          <meta name="PageID" content="ConvergedSignIn" />
          <meta name="SiteID" content="" />
          <meta name="ReqLC" content="1033" />
          <meta name="LocLC" content="en-US" />
      
              <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
      
              <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
      
          <noscript>
              <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://login.microsoftonline.com/jsdisabled" />
          </noscript>
      
          
          
      <meta name="robots" content="none" />
      
      <script type="text/javascript">//<... JS code here ...></script>
          
      </body>
      </html>
```

So, I receive the HTML page.
The API call returns me a 200 status code and a redirect URL like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_info={client_info}
```

How can I get the API content response by handling Microsoft redirecting?

Comment: are you including the bearer token in the header while making get call?

Comment: Yes, I include the access token retrieved from the Azure login and add it as bearer token.

Comment: If I use a cookie retrieved from web login, it works. But with the bearer token I still have this issue.